# Можно ли не ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

> Как чайка(,) парус белеет в высоте.

Может ли на первый план выйти значение образа – "белеть чайкой". Конечно, странно звучит, но все же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это строчка (правда, пропущено одно слово) из стихотворения А. Фета [«Старый парк»](https://stihpro.com/staryy-park/), написанного в 1853 году. В электронных версиях, попавшихся мне, запятая стоит.

***Как чайка, парус там белеет в высоте.**

Я жду, потонет он, но он не утопает

И, медленно скользя по выгнутой черте,

**Как волокнистый след пропавшей тучки** тает.* (А вот здесь нет запятой.)

Не думаю, что стóит искать образ действия, хотя, скорее всего, он присутствует. И не обязательно, чтобы замена творительным падежом (***чайкой***) или наречием (***по-чайковски*** ☺) хорошо звучала. Пусть будет чистое сравнение. А на обособление влияет и структура предложения, начальная позиция оборота. В конце, вероятно, запятой бы не было: *Парус там белеет как чайка*.

Кстати, в этом стихе есть ещё несколько оборотов с "как", и пунктуация везде понятна:

*И горная тропа, размытая водой,

Виясь **как желтый змей,** бежит на дно долины.*

*И солнце вырвалось из тучи, и лучи,

Блеснув **как молния,** в долину долетели.*

*А там, за соснами, **как купол голубой,**

Стоит бесстрастное, безжалостное море.*

В Нацкорпусе нашлось только одно предложение с чайками без запятых:

*Обломки различных конструкций **как чайки** летали над российской столицей* (А. М. Городницкий. Тайны и мифы науки. В поисках истины. 2014).

**Добавление**

Не буду править ответ, а просто напишу свои соображения. После анализа всего стихотворения и очередного прочтения небезызвестного параграфа Розенталя, думаю, важно отметить следующее:

1. Сравнительный оборот в качестве образа действия, как правило, примыкает к самому действию: *как град посыпалась; как демон коварна и зла; как гром загремел, как сталь засверкал; как буран летит, как вьюга спешит.* "У нас" не так.
2. А главное – интонация и расстановка акцентов. *Парус* в стихотворении появляется впервые. Если бы о нём уже шла речь, то вариант без запятой выглядел бы нормально, с выделением характеристики (образности) действия:
   *Как ч**А**йка парус там белеет в высоте* (аналогичный пример: *Как зарн**И**цы в небе они запылали* – понятно, что о "них" уже говорилось),
   но нам нужно ввести "нового героя", именно на него должно падать логическое ударение, а оборот произносится как бы попутно:
   *Как чайка, п**А**рус там белеет...*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142825/discussion-on-answer-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.